# Select the zone where to draw shadows with DirectionalLight

Tags: three.js

I use a directional light to cast shadow on the ground of my scene. I only have a single object. I decided to have a very small shadow to keep good shadow quality. The problem is I can't manage to shift the position of the shadow camera and keep it on top of the object.

I tried several things.

- Targeting my object works but the center of the camera don't change, just its angle. I don't want this behavior. I want to keep the same light direction.
- Changing the shadowCameraRight of the light but nothing change
- Changing the shadowCameraRight of the shadowCamera, nothing change
- changing the position of the sahdowCamera. The "debugger" moves but the shadow stop being drawn as if I did not do anyting

I think there must be a pretty easy way of doing this but I could not find it.

Edit :

```
var light = THREE.DirectionalLight(...);
var myObject = THREE.Mesh(); //moving everyFrame
//here I just want to move the shadowCamera so the object stay in the frustum
```

Best

Comment: Can we have a picture please

Comment: You want a picture of what in particular ?

Comment: without any code or even a jsfiddle not much help can be offered. maybe these fiddles will help: http://jsfiddle.net/4Txgp/13/, http://jsfiddle.net/wp6E3/4/, http://jsfiddle.net/abadabanades/95t964o0/13/

Comment: You could use a `SpotLight`. It has a position so you can place it on top of the cube.

Comment: @gaitat I have the same as the 2 first JsFiddle you gave. But I just want to move the center of the camera. In your example they are fixed. I Cannot give you a jsfiddle because the code is spread across several AMD modules. I don't have any code to give any code but I will try to explain what I exactly have in my post.

Comment: @marcel I know but I want to have the light to behave as if it was the sun. A spotlight is not the solution here unfortunately.

Comment: what do you mean "move the center of the camera". I assume you mean the shadowcamera. you have to move the light to move the shadow camera which is what fiddle 3 shows.

Comment: @gaitat In the third fiddle we have a spotlight and not a directional light. Moreover the direction is changing (I managed to do this as stated in my post) but the origin of the camera does not move.

Comment: if you look at the third fiddle in the animate loop the code to move the light is commented so you can move the light and so the shadowcamera.

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I can't accept your answer because it is a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using an Object3D?

```
var light = THREE.DirectionalLight(...);
var myObject = THREE.Mesh();

val allTogether = new Object3D();
allTogether.add(light);
allTogether.add(myObject);
// here set light position you want (relative)

scene.add(allTogether);
```

In your loop move the Object3D not your mesh, so everything is moved along.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. I will try it tomorrow ant let you know about the results.

Comment: Thank you for your proposition but I ended up using the solution suggested by gaitat.